# VS Code Source Control Pane is Blank

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control

I've reinstalled my PC and tried connecting back up to my Azure DevOps Repo using VS Code and TFVC. I'm using TFVC Location with Visual Studio 2019 Community TF.exe. It all seems to work and I can connect to my repo with my credentials. It all seems to load up fine and I can even see TFVC with a number of changes/differences. - see image below. However I'm expecting to see my source control and list of files to commit like before. But the panel is blank. There's no errors in the Output window of VS Code either.

I've tried removing and re-adding the workspace. Tried editing/adding anew file to the project in hope of kickstarting TFVC pane to show the file list. - the number next to TFVC updates but I don't see any menu button or files list.

Has anyone else had this and know a solution, or know where I'm going wrong.

[image: vscode tfvc]

Comment: The '40' number showing under Source Control is my Git Repository just to clarify.

Comment: You can edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue opened on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82374
For now I've rolled back to the August update and that's resolved it.

Comment: That’s exactly what I had to do to solve my problem. My old PC had the August version too. Thanks for posting your answer for others. I forgot to update my question.

Comment: The latest release has resolved this issue so feel free to update again.

Answer (score 31):

Just toggle `"scm.alwaysShowProviders"` on and off from whatever value your have (default is false), this would cause the source control pane to redraw and fix the issue for now.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: Also solved it for me after trying some other stuff. thanks

Comment: For those wondering how to do this:
1) File --> Preferences --> Settings opens up the Settings tab;
2) In the search bar paste "scm.alwaysShowProviders";
3) The checkbox you're looking for should come up in the results;

Answer (score 6):

I believe per the issues in GitHub that this issue is fixed for most people as of VSCode version 1.39.2, but I was still seeing it for projects based on a Git repo.

After some trial and error I found this setting was the culprit: `"scm.alwaysShowProviders": true`

When I remove that setting, or set it to `false`, my Source Control pane works correctly.

Answer (score 6):

This happens to me occasionally. I just figured out I can fix this by right clicking in the blank area and then selecting the repository I want to show up

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the blank area and slecting repo does the trick

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on the 1.55 version, as it's centrally controlled I couldn't manually update, but when they pushed the 1.64 version through, the problem has gone away, was driving me mad!